# 2D Point Light XNA , Why my point light radius is Oval?

Tags: xna-4.0, shaders, lighting

I friend of mine , taught me how to make a simple 2d point light with shader, so i follow his steps and finally done it !

but something happend , the light shape is like an oval and not like a circle , my friends couldnt explain me why,

could you help me how to fix it, and explain me why it happend?

here is how it looks like http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2553973/screengrab/PointLight_07.png

ShaderCode

```
Texture InputTexture;

sampler InputTextureSampler = sampler_state {
    texture = <InputTexture>;
    magfilter = LINEAR;
    minfilter = LINEAR;
    mipfilter = LINEAR;
    AddressU = mirror;
    AddressV = mirror;
};

struct VertexShaderOutput
{
    float4 Position  : POSITION0;
    float2 TexCoord  : TEXCOORD0;
    float4 Color     : COLOR0;
};

float4      ambientColor = float4(1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0);
float       ambientIntensity = 0.3f;


float4 PixelShaderFunction(VertexShaderOutput input) : COLOR0
{
    //float4 color = float4(1, 0, 0, 1);
    float4 texCol = tex2D(InputTextureSampler, input.TexCoord);

    float4 color = ambientIntensity*ambientColor;
    float dist;

    //Light 1
    float  lightRadius = 0.2f;
    float  lightIntensity = 15.0f;
    float4 lightPos = float4(0.3f,0.3f,0.0f,0); 
    float4 lightColor =  float4(0, 0, 1, 1);

        dist = distance(lightPos, input.TexCoord);
    color += saturate((lightRadius-dist)*lightIntensity)*lightColor;

    texCol = saturate(color) *texCol;


    return texCol;
}

technique PointLight
{
    pass Pass1
    {
        PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 PixelShaderFunction();
    }
}
```

XNA CODE

```
    GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(normalRender);
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);
    spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.AlphaBlend, null, null, null, effectLight);
      spriteBatch.Draw(background, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);
    spriteBatch.End();

    normalRenderTexture = normalRender;

    GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);
    spriteBatch.Begin();
       spriteBatch.Draw(normalRenderTexture, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);
    spriteBatch.End();
```

Comment: Could you zip the visual studio project and put it on your dropbox? I would like to download it and help you out.

Comment: @LuisEstrada http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2553973/PointLightXNA.zip , here is the project, the light is coded inside the Shader, is just a sample project :D, btw XNA 4.0

Comment: for a quick fix please change the size of your image to be a square. I will explain why soon.

Comment: @LuisEstrada it tottaly worked, i imagine why, because the aspect ratio of the texcoords of the image isnt square, but, is there any solution to keep using non square images?

Comment: I modified your code a bit to get a simple solution. See attached: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/29838828/PointLightXNA.zip

Comment: were you able to look at what i did?

Answer (score 2):

You need to take into account the AspectRatio of your viewport (GraphicsDevice.Viewport.AspectRatio), the texture coordinates given to the shader are normalized to a square region so you need to inform the shader of what your AspectRatio is.

In 3D you do this with the Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView call, in 2D you simply need to make a float aspectRatio which you initialize in XNA.

Comment: oh i see, i understand, but how i inform to the shader of the aspect ratio? , i need multiply this var with something? like the distance?

Comment: It actually doesn't have to do with the screen size or viewport. If you change the screen size to be a square (AspectRatio = 1.0) you get the same effect.

Comment: @Joyal When you map the UV coordinates to your light texture with 800x600, moving to the right 1/800 will swap one pixel to the right, and 1/600 a pixel to the bottom. I don't know if I'm making sense here. Basically you want to divide the U coordinate with the aspectratio (I believe it is, can't look it up right now, if not the U then the V). Setting it in the shader is just a simple matter of doing shader.Parameters["aspectratio"].SetValue I believe, again don't have the doc or ide in front of me.

Comment: @LuisEstrada Making the viewport (which is the same as screen size in fullscreen) into 1:1 simply means that modifying the UV coordinates is not necessary since they are already 1:1. 5*1 = 5/1 = 5. But unless your okay with that restriction you need to account for the aspectratio in your shader since it gives fractional coordinates that are mapped to be 1:1